# iOS Apps not showing up in Visual Studio AppCenter for 1 user

Tags: ios, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using VS AppCenter (Appcenter.ms) to distribute an iOS app to my beta testers.  For most of them everything is fine.  However, one user is unable to see anything (the one who is paying for everything naturally).
He says his phone is registered.  He receives the emails from AppCenter whenever I push a new build, but when he follows the link he is shown a blank page.
Has anybody else experienced this? 
I've searched but not found anything relevant.
TIA

Comment: Hi Jake, have you asked in the Intercom chat window? If you log in to appcenter.ms, it's the little icon on the bottom right. That will get you routed to the correct department and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: No, should have tried that.  But we figured it out after comparing the users having trouble with the user who were able to test the app.

Answer (score 0):

The users in question were added to the organization but not the apps being tested.  You have to either add the user to a group that has been assigned to the group or add the user directly to the app being tested.